# Wait callback with Promise.mapSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, sails.js, bluebird

I have a this:

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
{
    return Promise.mapSeries(array, function(field)
    {
        var objCb = {};
        var params = {};

        objCb.ok = function () {};
        objCb.send = function (data)
        {
            errors.push(data.message);
        };
        objCb.negociate = function (err)
        {
            errors.push(data.message);
        };

        theFunction(params, objCb);
    }
}
```

I have test multiple solutions, but don't work:

```
        return Promise.promisify(theFunction(params, objCb), {multiArgs: true});
```

and

```
        return Promise.fromCallback(function (objCb)
        {
            return theFunction(params, objCb);
        }, {multiArgs: true}).spread(function (a)
        {
            console.log("==== 1");
            console.log(a);
        });
```

If you have a solution to wait a callback or convert into promise (without edit the function (theFunction)) in a mapSeries, I would be delighted to learn it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.mapSeries` returns a promise, so you don't need to re-wrap it.

```
Promise.mapSeries(array, function(field)
{
    return new Promise( function(resolve, reject)
        {
        var objCb = {};
        var params = {};

        objCb.ok = function (resolve()) {};
        objCb.send = function (data)
        {
            reject(data.message);
        };
        objCb.negociate = function (err)
        {
            reject(data.message);
        };

        theFunction(params, objCb);
    }
}
```

Note: `mapSeries` will stop on the first error it encounters.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but not work, mapSeries wait indefinitely.

Oh wait, no enter in my condition, I test and I will respond suddenly.

Comment: It work, I continue testing, but apparently it work fine. Thanks.